# Is limiting the type and size of a field inside of the database enough for security?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, security

**MS SQL 2008:** I tried searching for this but didn't really find an answer. I know that all user input should be sanitized and validated before being saved to the database, but I'm wondering if that is also necessary for fields that are limited in the database by size and type.

For example, I have several fields that are of BIT type and would only allow 1 character, or INT fields that have a foreign key designation, so only foreign keys can be saved into it.

So now, on a form where I have a user send a message to another user, I could have

1. Radio button BIT (contact me yes/no)
2. hidden field (send to #userid#) so this will place the ID of the user into the table
3. DateTime field (message sent on *this* date) Will be automatically populated by me, but I'm throwing it in here, let's say I let the user set the time.
4. VarChar (max size 2), this one I wonder about, I'm guessing even just being limited to 2, a person could inject something malicious into it?

Do I need to sanitize these fields before sending them to the database, or will the database handle and reject the input?

The reason I'm asking all of this, is to find out what is generally accepted and also for performance reasons.

Thanks.

Comment: Your column may be a `char(1)`, which doesn't stop me from sending `; DROP tbl`

Comment: But it wouldn't be inserted into the table, so what's the point?

Comment: Because the table will be dropped... The application must do the sanitation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sanitize your inputs to prevent malicious users from modifying your SQL query through the data to do something bad. I don't think changing the type or size will contribute to the security of your system. Your DBMS will reject any inserts where the data is of the wrong size or type.

Comment: I don't understand, you say that my DBMS will reject all data of wrong type or size, so why would I need to sanitize the input in my example above? If my field in the table is BIT type, how can a use insert '; DROP tbl' into it?

Comment: because you can do something like: 1'; DROP tbl; --. Here "1" is the bit part and I conclude it with ', but then I continue to tell your DBMS to drop tables (as an additional query). Thus the insert will go through (that bit column will have value 1), but then the next query will delete the whole table.

Comment: The attack isn't about inserting something into the DB that you shouldn't, but rather about fooling your DBMS to execute a query that you didn't specify.

Comment: oh... I didn't realize that is how it worked. I'm glad I asked this question before making my app live. I guess I'll have to validate, sanitize EVERYTHING coming from the user, there are no shortcuts :\

Answer (score 1):

Datatypes are not the answer to security.  Datatypes should be appropriate for your business requirements.  For example, if you have a requirement to allow people to rich text paragraphs,  such as I am doing right now,  (see ***rich text***), then a char(10) field with html stripped out might be secure, but useless.

You've already been briefed a bit on sql injection.  You also have to take heed of malicious html and javascript.  Just for fun, insert this:

```
<script>alert("oh dear");</script>
```

into your database.  Then write a simple .net/php/coldfusion/whatever app that selects it and displays it on a web page.  Dollars to donuts it executes.

Your question has already been answered.  This is just more stuff to consider.